# Argument is the Wrong Type

Tags: variables, turing-lang

I am trying to make a pie graph by using **drawarc** and user inputted values, but after I calculate the angle, and try to draw the arc I get this error, "Argument is the Wrong Type" for item1Angle. Any Help?

```
var item1 : int
var item2 : int
var item3 : int
var allItems : int
var item1Angle : real
var item2Angle : real
var item3Angle : real
%Ending Angle for First Sector = starting for second
put "Please Enter The First Item Cost"
get item1

put "Please Enter The Second Item Cost"
get item2

put "Please Enter The Third Item Cost"
get item3

allItems := item1 + item2 + item3

item1Angle := (360/allItems) * item1
item2Angle := (360/allItems) * item2
item3Angle := (360/allItems) * item3

drawfillarc (100,100,50,50, item1Angle, item2Angle)
drawfillarc (100,100,50,50, item2Angle, item3Angle)
drawfillarc (100,100,50,50, item3Angle, item1Angle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I had to use the **Round** function, like so:

```
item1Round := round (item1Angle)
```